# Query for Joining two tables to get result from 2nd table in reference

Tags: mysql

I have two tables Order and Transaction

**Order** Table

| id | OrderId | TransId | OrderDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 54 | 11551 | 01-12-2021 |
| 2 | 55 | 11552 | 02-12-2021 |
| 3 | 56 | 11553 | 02-12-2021 |
| 4 | 57 | 11554 | 05-12-2021 |
| 5 | 58 | 11555 | 08-12-2021 |
| 6 | 59 | 11556 | 09-12-2021 |

**Transaction** Table

| id | TransId | OrderId | PaymentMethod | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11551-1 | 54 | Cash | 1000 |
| 2 | 11552-1 | 55 | Cash | 500 |
| 3 | 11552-2 | 55 | Card | 200 |
| 4 | 11553-1 | 56 | Cash | 500 |
| 5 | 11553-2 | 56 | Card | 200 |
| 6 | 11553-3 | 56 | UPI | 100 |

Here we have 3 Transaction methods Cash, Card and UPI.

I want to get total *Amount* collected using **Cash** as *PaymentMethod* done for  period  01-12-2021 to 08-12-2021 in orderDate of Order Table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t.paymentMethod, sum(t.amount) from tbl_order o
inner join tbl_transaction t on o.orderId = t.orderId 
where t.paymentMethod = 'CASH' and o.orderDate between start_date and end_date
group by t.paymentMethod;
```